# Oracle order by varchar2 with numeric values in it

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by

I have an issue where a Oracle DB column(say 'REF_NO') is VARCHAR2 and carries values similar to the ones below
If I do an ORDER BY REF_NO I get this:

```
LET-2-1
LET-2-10
LET-2-11
LET-2-2
LET-2-3
```

Which makes sense because the values are being treated as characters. I have been asked to change this so that the returned results are ordered like this:

```
LET-2-1
LET-2-2
LET-2-3
LET-2-10
LET-2-11
```

I cannot guarantee the format of these values either so I cannot really see how I can use regex or sub-string as it's a completely free text entry for users to enter values. The example above just happens to be what the requested data looks like. Other data could be completely different.

I cannot see how this is possible, so was hoping for some suggestions.

**Additional information**

To add to the complexity, here are some more examples from other customers:

```
Customer 1: OB 12, WE-11, WAN-001
Customer 2: P4, D1, W9
Customer 3: NTT-33A, RLC-33L, ARR-129B
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from TABLE 
ORDER BY LENGTH(REF_NO), REF_NO
```

first you need to order by length and then order by REF_NO

Comment: It's close and seems to work for the particular customer I have the request for. But as I say, there is no real restrictions or formats for this columns data, so what works for them, doesn't work for others. I think this is going to have to be a rejected request or looking at a restructuring of our database (include a 'display order' column). Thanks for the effort, it was a close one.

Comment: @KPS-US it seems troublesome. Every row in a column should have a common format. Otherwise you will have to change your query every time whenever you have a new format so make every row have a common format or seperate columns to different columns. I don't know your table's design so couldn't give you any advise about that. GL.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps

```
create table test01 (c varchar2(30));
insert into test01 values ('LET-2-1');
insert into test01 values ('LET-2-10');
insert into test01 values ('LET-2-2');
```

Query

```
select * from test01 
order by to_number(SUBSTR(C,INSTR(C,'-',1)+1,INSTR(C,'-',1,2)-INSTR(C,'-',1)-1)),
to_number(SUBSTR(C,INSTR(C,'-',-1)+1));
```

Assuming all the values are having structure of -- - in the above query I try to extract numbers and converted to number in order by clause.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, see my comments for Burak Karasoy. But thanks for your efforts